Does Mean Value Theorem on Putnam 2014 A5 work?
The Putnam 2014 A5 question is as follows:
Let $$P_n(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + · · · + nx^{n−1}.$$
Prove that the polynomials $P_j(x)$ and $P_k(x)$ are relatively
prime for all positive integers $j$ and $k$ with $j \neq k$.
I came up with a solution using the mean value theorem, but I couldn't find any similar solutions online to verify. I'm not sure if it's correct, and if not, I was wondering where the proof breaks down?
This is what I came up with:
Let j, k be positive integers with $j\neq k$. WLOG let $k>j$. Suppose by contradiction $P_j(x)$ and $P_k(x)$ are not relatively prime, ie $P_j(r) = P_k(r) = 0$ for some r. Then $$(r-1)^2P_k(r) = (r-1)^2P_j(r) = 0 $$ $$\implies (r-1)^2P_k(r) - (r-1)^2P_j(r) = 0$$
Let $$f(m) = (r-1)^2P_m(r) = mr^{m+1} - (m+1)r^m - 1$$
Then the above statement is equivalent to $f(k) - f(j) = 0$. By the Mean Value Theorem, we have $$ 0 = \frac{f(k) - f(j)}{k-j} = f'(d)$$ for some $d\in [j, k]$
Then $$f'(d) = d(d+1)r^d - d(d+1)r^{d-1} = d(d+1)r^{d-1}(r-1) = 0.$$ Note this is only true if $d=0, d=-1, r= 1$, or $ r=0$. If $d \leq 0$, then $j \leq 0$, a contradiction. Further note $P_k(1), P_k(0) > 0$, so $r$ cannot be $0$ or $1$. Therefore by contradiction, $P_j(x)$ and $P_k(x)$ are relatively prime.
One caveat here is after reading other solutions, I realized $r$ can be complex, so I'm not sure how that affects using the MVT. If anyone could help me out, that would be appreciated.

Yes $r$ may be complex. Moreover, your computation of $f'(d)$ is not correct. You have to derive $f(m)$ with regard to $m$, not $r$.

Even before that, note that your function $f$ is from integers to reals. (EG what is $f( 0.5)$? Are you claiming $ 1+ 0.5\sqrt{x}$?), so it doesn't make sense to talk about MVT on such a function. $\quad$ We can't extend that idea either, since it is entirely possible for $f(k) - f(j) = 0 $, but no other $f(k') - f(j') = 0 $ for $k', j'$ integers in $[k, j]$.

And of course, we're only saying that your solution doesn't work. There might be some other way to apply the MVT somehow to get at a solution. So it's very hard to answer the question in the title in the negative.

Yeah, so I fixed the computation of $f'(d)$ on paper and tried working it out again, it seems to completely fizzle out as far as I can tell, I'll probably close the post.
